# F# Ionide - FAKE build "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: f#, f#-fake, ionide

I am working with F# on Windows with the Ionide plug-in. I can create a new F# project and load one of the example templates, e.g. "fslabjournal" or a class library.

Working in the script files seems fine, and everything in the default scripts works as expected. However, I cannot work out how to build anything. I would have thought that trying "FAKE: build" and choosing the "Clean" option would get me started, but all I get is a "The system cannot find the path specified." message.

Is this what I should expect to see when building default templates? Is there more setup to be done to these before a build can happen?

Comment: FSLabjournal is a bit special so ignore that for the time being. Just create a new Console application with "Hello World" in it. Then with Ctrl+Shift+P` type msbuild, and pick build current project (`Ctrl+Alt+B`). That should build it for you and put the exe somewhere under the bin folder. In the Project Explorer it should show your project if it is correctly restored. On Windows you could also try VS2017. Do you have anything non-standard in your path name?

Comment: I've tried this with the "PigLatin" demo code from MS's getting started guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-vscode?tabs=windows). Strangely, I'm getting no response from "MSBuild: build project" - no error messages, but no sign of anything happening in the bin folder. I can see the project in VS code's F# project explorer, and right clicking it gives build options - but none of these seem to give any response.

Comment: that example is a bit complex to follow, you don't need any code, just do a simple "Hello World" app. If you have issues with Code, try VS2017. Regarding MSBuild's output, Ionide hides it by default (you can turn that off in preferences) but you can always bring it up, from VSCode, select the Output tab at the bottom and switch it to `msbuild` in the pull-down menu on the lower right. It will tell you exactly what is happening with msbuild and where the exe went. You can also push your repo to GitHub if you want someone to check if it builds.

Comment: as usual it might be easier in the [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/) or in the [Chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)